# How can we find the limit of ln?

Tags: limits

First of all I tried to solve this limit problem which says: 
 
limit x->0 (x^2)*ln(1/x) 
 
What I've tried is limit x->0 -x^2*lnx, but I couldn't complete since plugging x is 0*0 = 0 so the limit is 0 or what?

Comment: Hint: Let $x = e^u$.

Comment: If $x$ tends to $0$ (from the right), $\ln(1/x)$ tends to $\infty$, so you cannot just plug in $x=0$. And $\ln(x)$ tends to $-\infty$; the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \left[ { x }^{ 2 }\ln { \left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  }  \right]  } =-\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \ln { x }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  }  } \overset { L'Hospital's }{ = } -\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \frac { 1 }{ x }  }{ \frac { -2 }{ { x }^{ 3 } }  }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } =0 } $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n=e^{-n}$, which tends to $0$. Then

$$t_n=ne^{-2n}$$
 and
$$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}=\frac{n+1}{ne^2}<\frac2{e^2}$$

so that the sequence converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 0. Use L'hôpital rule to find limits of such forms as this. Convert this into a 0/0 form first by taking the x^2 to the denominator.